# Different boost log sinks for every class

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I am new to boost log.

My algorithm has 4 main steps and I want the logging for every step in one file. So that I have 4 sinks. My idea is that I can change the sink on every step. Is that possible?

At the moment I have my `looger.h` with a global logger

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H_
#define LOGGER_H_

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/formatter_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

enum sign_severity_level {
  trace,
  debug,
  info,
  warning,
  error,
  fatal,
  report
};

void InitLog()
{
    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_ostream_backend> TextSink;

    // init sink1
    boost::shared_ptr<sinks::text_ostream_backend> backend1 = boost::make_shared<sinks::text_ostream_backend>();
    backend1->add_stream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(new std::ofstream("sign.log")));
    backend1->auto_flush(true);
    boost::shared_ptr<TextSink> sink1(new TextSink(backend1));
    sink1->set_formatter(
            expr::format("[%1%]<%2%>(%3%): %4%") % expr::format_date_time < boost::posix_time::ptime
                    > ("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") % expr::attr < sign_severity_level > ("Severity") % expr::attr
                    < attrs::current_thread_id::value_type > ("ThreadID") % expr::smessage);
    sink1->set_filter(expr::attr < sign_severity_level > ("Severity") >= warning);
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink1);

    logging::add_common_attributes();
    logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("ThreadID", attrs::current_thread_id());
}
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt<sign_severity_level>)


#endif /* LOGGER_H_ */
```

Is it possible to change the sink after every step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change only stream of a sink:

```
void set_log_file(const char* filename) {
  backend_->remove_stream(current_stream_);
  current_stream_.reset(new std::ofstream(filename));
  backend_->add_stream(current_stream_);
}
```

Usage:

```
manager.set_log_file("log_1.txt");
BOOST_LOG_SEV(log, error) << "This will go to log_1";
BOOST_LOG_SEV(log, error) << "And this one";

manager.set_log_file("log_2.txt");
BOOST_LOG_SEV(log, error) << "This will go to log_2";

manager.set_log_file("log_3.txt");
BOOST_LOG_SEV(log, error) << "This will go to log_3";
```

Result:

```
> cat log_1.txt
[...]<4>(0x00007fe742977780): This will go to log_1
[...]<4>(0x00007fe742977780): And this one
> cat log_2.txt
[...]<4>(0x00007fe742977780): This will go to log_2
> cat log_3.txt
[...]<4>(0x00007fe742977780): This will go to log_3
```

- Full example: http://pastebin.com/e3qDQ8tT

Comment: nice exmaple thank you. I only have to change using Backend...  in typedef.

Comment: thank you I use the old standard. One more question how i can modify the logger in this way that it didn't delete the existing files. Because i have one main.log and a few step.log i am switching between main and the steps. But on every switch it resets the main.log

Comment: i tested text_file_backend, but with this it is not possible to manual change the name of the log file

Comment: @Hunk I figure out that you can simply change the [openmode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) of `ofstream`: `current_stream_.reset(new std::ofstream(filename, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app));`

Comment: the openmode with ofstream works well now. With text_file_backend is also possible, but then i can't add or remove new files with "set_log_file". I didn't find any similar functions on text_file_backend. Did I missed something?