# Boost log incorrect log

Tags: c++, logging, boost

i have a easy struct

```
struct Test {
  std::vector<int> values;
  int value;
}
```

with overloaded << operator

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p, const Test& t)
{
    p << "test: ";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < t.values.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << t.values[i] << " ";
    }
    p << " value: " << t.value << std::endl;
    return p;
}
```

this works fine when i use the default output. But when i am using my boost logge, shown here [Different boost log sinks for every class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037206/different-boost-log-sinks-for-every-class), it print the values inside my console and the rest inside my file. Anyone has an idea what happens there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::cout << t.values[i] << " ";
```

should be

```
p << t.values[i] << " ";
```

Comment: i was blind ... thank you very much